# Ubuntu 16.04: Error return on gem install bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jekyll, bundler

I've been getting a return,

```
~$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

When trying to install Jekyll via gem bundler

I've found lots of resources of others getting this error such as,

I've recompiled ruby after `sudo apt-get libssl-dev` as well as a few other dep/libs I could think of,

but no results. Any other ideas someone has?

Setup:
Dell 2120
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: what is the output of `gem install bundler --debug`?

Comment: https://www.scribd.com/document/341365762/Terminal

Answer (score 1):

The package zlib is missing and causes the installer to fail.

You need to install it like:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was following the respective [issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/55) on the official Jekyll repository in GitHub.

#### Performing the following steps, I got it to work:

Remove any previously installed versions:

```
sudo apt-get purge jekyll
sudo apt-get purge ruby
```

Install ruby anew:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties
sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
rvm install 
rvm install 2.4.1
rvm use 2.4.1 --default
```

Make sure you have, NodeJS and Python installed, if not - do so by:

```
sudo apt-get install node
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

And at last,

```
gem install jekyll
```

#### Result:

```
jekyll -v
jekyll 3.4.3
```

Of course, now you could execute `gem install bundler` smoothly, too.

Hope this helps!